# WPF .Net programming

Tags: wpf

Difference between Close() method and App.current.ShutDown()  method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) set to either `OnMainWindowClose` or `OnLastWindowClose` and you're talking about the Close() method of a form that is either the main window or the last window, then nothing because Shutdown will be called in those situations.